# How to structure Dynamo 'posts' table(s) to enable querying by user ID OR post timestamp?

Tags: nosql, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries, amazon-dynamodb-index

I'm working on a "Buffer-like" (scheduled posts) type application and looking into Dynamo as the data store. I'm more familiar with SQL and am having a little trouble wrapping my head around how best to accomplish this in Dynamo (or if Dynamo is even the right choice given the requirements).

Basics:

- Users create posts that are scheduled to be posted at a later date/time (Unix timestamp).
- Posts are stored in a Posts table in Dynamo.

Desired functionality/query-ability:

- For sake of editing/retrieving scheduled posts, want to be able to query by user ID to retrieve all posts by a given user ID.
- On the other hand, when it comes to executing scheduled posts at the appropriate time, would like to have a 'regular' job that runs and sweeps through to find all posts scheduled for, say, the next 15 minutes, based on the timestamp.

Where I'm stumped:

- For sake of querying posts, it makes sense to have the user ID be the partition key and a unique post ID serve as the sort key (I think). Using timestamp as the sort key isn't doable as there's no guarantee that user ID + timestamp will be unique.
- On the other hand, for executing scheduled posts, user ID is somewhat irrelevant and I just need all posts scheduled in a window between two timestamps (IE the next 15 minutes). Even if the partition key was YYYYMMDD and the sort key was the timestamp this still wouldn't work as again it wouldn't necessarily be unique. And I'd lose the ability to easily query for all posts by a given user ID.

My thought is that user ID = partition key and unique post ID = sort key, and that the timestamp need could be accomplished by a GSI, but then that still would necessitate querying across all partitions, no? (again, still wrapping my head around GSIs)

In summation, wondering if A) This is even feasible with Dynamo and if so how best to accomplish, and B) If I'm trying to fit a square peg in a round hole and should be looking at a different data store option entirely.

Thanks in advance for any help here!

Answer (score 1):

Create a GSI. For the PK provide a constant "Timeline" or whatever so all items go under the same partition. For the SK provide the timestamp. Then you can easily and efficiently Query against the GSI for all posts within a date range (regardless of user). The base table's PK and SK will be projected in so you can pull the post-id from the GSI.

If your write activity is > 1,000 new blog posts per second you'll want to think about adding some write sharding.